# Does using local variables (instead of repeated property access) ever hurt performance?

Tags: javascript, performance, properties, local-variables

I've been looking over some JavaScript code that is designed to be run in a performance-sensitive environment, mainly a game engine in *mobile environments*.

In many cases this code doesn't use local variables but instead prefers to use explicit chains, e.g.

```
if (this.x.y[z].i) {
    this.x.y[z].a += this.x.y[z].b;
}
```

Where both `this.x.y` and `this.x.y.z` represent "duplication" - and where none of the intermediate properties have getters, and where `q` is a local variable not used elsewhere - can be treated semantically equivalent to the following.

```
var q = this.x.y[z]
if (q.i) {
    q.a += q.b;
}
```

(The names have been kept vague particularly to try and mitigate bias; this question is not about which "pattern" to follow - although I do prefer the latter and intend to use it 100% and thus am asking this question.)

Now, before I get a whole slew of comments talking about "write code for clarity" and "don't prematurely optimize", keep reading!

So given the following assertions/axiom and noting that this question is *not* about how to improve performance, but rather if using local cache/"alias" variables can *decrease* performance on relevant JavaScript implementations:

- Introducing a local variable, when a member is accessed many times, will lead to more clear code. (This is subjective, but is an axiom for sake of the question.)
- Using a local variable, as shown, for non-dynamically properties will always have the same semantics.
- There are *no* closures being created over the local variables; as such there is no concern for increasing object lifetimes or otherwise holding onto a larger execution context scope.
- Focus is on *mobile* browsers, including non/low-JIT varieties - e.g. JavaScriptCore and/or whatever was about on Android before V8.
- Browsers are already well-optimized for this case and it is not expected that using a local variables will result in any noticeable "performance" increase - this question is about the opposite.

Can/will using local variables *instead* of [multiple] direct property access result in a *decrease* in performance? Where such a decrease is "non-negligible.."

Comment: The way you answer such a question is by testing. In general, caching a value in a local variable will never hurt performance and will probably improve it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer probably depends more on the browser than the code.  Consider that JavaScript was created to be "interpreted", meaning the code is parsed and executed as it is parsed.  In that scenario the declaration of a local variable gets parsed and executed every time the function is called, containing that variable-declaration.  That can't qualify as "fast".

However, modern JavaScript-processing engines are not doing things that way any more; they are essentially compiling the code when the web page loads.  The declaration of a local variable now gets processed once --along with declarations of all other variables, such as globals and object-properties.  In this scenario it is likely that there isn't a fastest way of variable declaration, for the person writing the code to prefer to use.